# How to compare two columns from the same data set?

Tags: python

I have a data set with 6 columns and 4.5 million rows, and I want to iterate through all the data set to compare the value of the last column with the value of the 1st column for each and every row in my data set and append the rows whose last column value matches the value of first column of a row to that row.

The first solution that came to my mind was using `.iter` from pandas, but I think it is too slow for large data sets.

let's assume this is my data set:

```
x = [['2', 'Jack', '8'],['1', 'Ali', '2'],['4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
['5' , 'gabe' , '2'],['100' , 'Jack' , '6'],
['7' , 'Ali' , '2'],['8' , 'nobody' , '20'],['9' , 'Al', '10']]
```

the result should  look something like this:

```
[['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5' , 'gabe' , '2','7' , 'Ali' , '2'],
 ['1', 'Ali', '2', '4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
['8' , 'nobody' , '20', '2', 'Jack', '8']]
```

The code I have tried is:

```
for line in x:
    arow=line
    for row in x:
        brow=row
        if line[2]==row[0]:
            brow.extend(arow)
            table.append(brow)

print(table)
```

but the results seem to repeat:

```
[['8', 'nobody', '20', '2', 'Jack', '8'],
 ['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5', 'gabe', '2', '7', 'Ali', '2'],
 ['1', 'Ali', '2', '4', 'sgee', '1'],
 ['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5', 'gabe', '2', '7', 'Ali', '2'], 
['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5', 'gabe', '2', '7', 'Ali', '2']]
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: how fast do you need it to run?

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang. yes! I edited my question. Thanks for reminding me. As you can see, my results repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using numpy, but this will take on the order of 10s of minutes.

```
import numpy as np
import time


x = [['2', 'Jack', '8'],['1', 'Ali', '2'],['4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
     ['5' , 'gabe' , '2'],['100' , 'Jack' , '6'],
     ['7' , 'Ali' , '2'],['8' , 'nobody' , '20'],['9' , 'Al', '10']] 

xArr = np.array(x)
st = time.time()
newList = []
for kk,i in enumerate(xArr):

    matches = np.where(xArr[:,-1]==i[0])[0]
    if len(matches)!=0:
        newList.append(np.concatenate([i,xArr[matches].flatten()]))

print('Runtime',time.time() - st)
```

Comment: this works, but also adds a ```dtype='<U6'``` at the end of each list. could you explain what it is? thanks a lot!

Comment: its just the data type (which is little endian (<) unicode (U) the number has to do with the size). Like an array can be 'int16' or 'uint16'. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing

Comment: your code works flawlessly for smaller data sets, but my computer crashes for "memory error." I have a 12 gigabyte computer, and my data set is about 650 MB. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: At what stage does it stop working? When converting to an array or running the loop. If its the latter, you could save results to a text file. If the former you could try using memmap? Probably you’ll need to use both.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

x = [['2', 'Jack', '8'],['1', 'Ali', '2'],['4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
['5' , 'gabe' , '2'],['100' , 'Jack' , '6'],
['7' , 'Ali' , '2'],['8' , 'nobody' , '20'],['9' , 'Al', '10']]

d = defaultdict(list)

for v in x:
    d[v[0]] += v
    d[v[-1]] += v

pprint([v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 3])
```

Prints:

```
[['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5', 'gabe', '2', '7', 'Ali', '2'],
 ['2', 'Jack', '8', '8', 'nobody', '20'],
 ['1', 'Ali', '2', '4', 'sgee', '1']]
```

Comment: this code works! thank  you. could you explain what "if len(v) > 3" does? thanks!

Comment: @Pie-ton 3 is number of columns (in this case). I want to filter-out results which don't have any match.