# how to append the rows using indexing (or any other method)?

Tags: database, sqlite, indexing

I have a data set with 6 columns and 4.5 million rows, and I want to iterate through all the data set to compare the value of the last column with the value of the 1st column for each and every row in my data set and append the rows whose last column value matches the value of first column of a row to that row. the first and last columns are indexed, but none are integers.

I asked the same question in stackoverflow and received a good answer which was based on numpy and arraying the data, but I am afraid it is too slow for a rather big dataset.

let's assume this is my data set (in the real data set, the first and last elements are not integers):

```
x = [['2', 'Jack', '8'],['1', 'Ali', '2'],['4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
['5' , 'gabe' , '2'],['100' , 'Jack' , '6'],
['7' , 'Ali' , '2'],['8' , 'nobody' , '20'],['9' , 'Al', '10']]
```

the result should look something like this:

```
[['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5' , 'gabe' , '2','7' , 'Ali' , '2'],
 ['1', 'Ali', '2', '4' , 'sgee' , '1'],
['8' , 'nobody' , '20', '2', 'Jack', '8']]
```

I think I can use indexing to make the process faster, but my knowledge of databases is very limited. Does anybody have a solution (using indexes or any other tool)?

the numpy solution for this question is below:
[How to compare two columns from the same data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894595/how-to-compare-two-columns-from-the-same-data-set/56894762?noredirect=1#comment100370598_56894762)

here is the link to a sample of the real data in sqlite: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11w-o4twH-hyRaX8KKvFLL6dQtkTKCJky

Comment: Is your data in a sql database or a python list?

Comment: I have it in both ```.csv``` and ```.sqlite``` format

Comment: Then you should include the sqlite table definition, any existing indexes, and what queries and code you've tried so far.

Comment: Note that sql queries can't return a variable number of columns, but you can easily return rows in a way that's trivial to build an arbitrary length list of related ones in python.

Comment: And why do you say you have six columns but that sample list appears to have three?

Comment: It is just an example. I thought if I know the code, I can tweak it to fit my data base.

Comment: I also added the link of a sample of the real data to the question if that helps

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have some problem, you've decided on a solution, and you're asking how to implement the solution. If you told us what the underlying problem is, why you're appending these things together, we might be able to come up with something better.

Comment: I absolutely welcome a better alternative! I just wanted to show what the final product should look like. If you look at my question, you will see I have said: "Does anybody have a solution (using indexes or any other tool)?" In other words, I said what I thought might work but kept an open mind for any alternative solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential SQL-based solution could go as follows (I'm using your big sample DB as a reference):

To make my proposed solution efficient I would do the following:

Create an index on the last column and create a partial index to eliminate rows where the first and last columns are the same. This is optional so you may remove this from the later query if you think this causes a problem. But if you do you should create a full index on col 0. All three are included here for completeness.

```
CREATE INDEX [index_my_tab_A] ON [tab]([0]);
CREATE INDEX [index_my_tab_B] ON [tab]([5]);
CREATE INDEX [index_my_tab_AB] ON [tab]([0]) where [0] != [5];
ANALYZE;
```

Then I would take advantage of join behavior to generate the listing you need to produce the result you are after. By joining the table to itself you can get multiple return rows for each row considered.

```
SELECT * from tab t1
JOIN tab t2 on t2.[5] = t1.[0] 
WHERE t1.[0] != t1.[5]
AND t2.[5] != 'N/A' -- Optional
ORDER by t1.[0];
```

Running that SQL against your big sample database (After ANALYZE step had completed) took 0.2 seconds on my machine. It produced three rows that matched which I presume to be correct.
It may not be immediately obvious what the resulting table means so here is the result the above query gives when run against the small sample you gave in your original post. (that SQL was modified ever so slightly to deal with the reduced number of columns) … when run it produced the following result which is equivalent to your original desired result:

```
1  Ali      2   4   sgee   1
2  Jack     8   1   Ali    2
2  Jack     8   5   gabe   2
2  Jack     8   7   Ali    2
8  Nobody  20   2   Jack   8
```

All you would have to do is run through this resulting list and combine the rows to produce the list you specified. The general idea here is to add the second trio of entries to the first trio of entries until the first trio of entries changes but only include the first trio of entries once.

So starting with the first line you would combine the Ali trio with the sgee trio giving you  ['1', 'Ali', '2', '4' , 'sgee' , '1']

You would then then combine the three Jack rows giving ['2', 'Jack', '8', '1', 'Ali', '2', '5' , 'gabe' , '2','7' , 'Ali' , '2']

then the final row combines to form ['8' , 'nobody' , '20', '2', 'Jack', '8']

This matches the three arrays you specified (although not in the same order)

Note: Your original question did not indicate what result you expected for the case where the first and last column match in the same row ... [3, George, 3]  so ... The where clause eliminates two kinds of entries. I noticed in your big sample data that there were many rows when col 0 and col 5 were the same. So the where clause eliminates these rows from consideration. The second thing I noticed was that many rows have 'N/A' in col 5 so I removed those from consideration too.

Comment: your solution reduced my calculation time from approximately 18 days to some seconds! Could you also educate me on how I should "run through this resulting list and combine the rows to produce the list?" also, how should I save the results?

Comment: @Pie-ton you could save the result in a new table that had 12 columns (matching your large database). The SQL query provided above can be used as the set of input values using an 'INSERT INTO resulttable SELECT …' statement.

Comment: @Pie-ton I thought I tried to explain the steps for running through the result list. The general idea is to enumerate through the left side grouping of values and every time the value in that position changes you have reached the end of the matched set.